# Rails - How do you dynamically call the request methods "get put destroy etc" at runtime in tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, dynamic

I'm always writing tests to check my controller restricts people from certain actions depending on their status i.e. logged in, admin? etc 
Regardless of whether its a get to :index or a puts to :create the code is always the same. I'm trying to refactor this so that i have one method such as

```
should_redirect_unauthenticated_to_login_action(request, action)
```

and call it like so

```
should_redirect_unauthenticated_to_login_action(:get, :index)  => get :index
```

But not sure how to dynamically call the various response methods rails provides for functional tests which seem to live in the module ActionController

I mucked around with

```
module = Kernel.const_get("ActionController")
module::TestProcess.get
NoMethodError: undefined method `get' for ActionController::TestProcess:Module
```

can anyone help (im very new to dynamic calling in ruby)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This goes in your test helper somewhere, or in any module that you can mix into your functional tests.

```
def should_redirect_unauthenticated_to_login_action(http_method, action, params = {})
  send http_method, action, params
  should_be_cool_and_stuff # assertions or whatever else goes here.
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Is [Object::send](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Object.html#M000333) what you're looking for?

As in

```
2.send(:+, 233) # --> 235
"Cake".send :reverse # --> "ekaC"

Kernel.const_get("A").const_get("B").send :cake; # runs A::B.cake
```

Answer (score 0):

The mapping of a path in combination with the HTTP-Method (get, post, etc.) to a controller and a method is done by the routing, not by the controller itself. So if you want to test what happens after you 'GET' '/users' and maybe want to test for a redirection, IntegrationTest is your thing:

```
get '/users'
assert_redirected_to :login
```

Hope this helps